# When calling a javascript function within another function, is it executed synchronously?

Tags: javascript

In the following code:

```
function doStuffA() {
 // DO SOME THINGS

 doStuffB();

 // DO SOME MORE THINGS
}
function doStuffB() {
// DO B THINGS
}
doStuffA();
```

What order is the code executed?

Is it:

```
1. DO SOME THINGS
2. DO B THINGS
3. DO SOME MORE THINGS
```

Or:

```
1. DO SOME THINGS
2. DO B THINGS & DO SOME MORE THINGS - AT THE SAME TIME
```

Comment: You're not calling `doStuffB` inside A, you have a syntax error. Function calls do not use the `function` keyword.

Comment: Of course it is. Except for async functions like AJAX calls

Comment: @Jonh sorry was just copying the code in the "comments" area of the function.

Comment: This isn't real code and it won't run. Can you please show us something feasible?

Comment: @bfavaretto sorry I just typed it out by hand and made a mistake.  Fixed.

Comment: @NullUserException I get an error for that http://jsfiddle.net/s3Y53/

Comment: Its good to see the js enthusiasts.  The comments run like an IM screen.

Comment: Okay, syntax error is gone, but you still aren't calling `doStuffA` anywhere, so `doStuffB` will never run.

Comment: @bfavaretto this isn't real code.  Is it more a theoretical question about how js executes functions.  Hence the reason I don't actually have anything in the functions (just comments).

Comment: @AmandaMyer Next time, please post real code (or at least code that does something). Look of how much discussion and how many non-answers that triggered...

Comment: @bfavaretto I wouldn't mind the having no real code, I think it's implied that `/* DO SOME THINGS */` is what is going to be executed. The problem is that even in its current form, no functions are actually called.

Comment: @NullUserException (and this will be my last comment on this topic): that's why a said *or at least code that does something*.

Comment: -1 Well, now the question makes sense but it's just bad. Functions in JS are synchronous (unless otherwise specified) so the answer is obvious. Everyone has a JS interpreter on their browser, so testing this requires minimal effort. I was hoping for the question to be actually interesting, like something involving closures and/or calls to functions right after their declaration. But this stuff is just trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you intended for there to be a call to `doStuffB` in `doStuffA`, and a call to `doStuffA` somewhere...

Javascript is traditionally executed synchronously.

Therefore:

```
1. DO SOME THINGS
2. DO B THINGS
3. DO SOME MORE THINGS
```

Comment: Was going to downvote this, but the question doesn't make sense. Nothing is actually called.

Comment: @NullUserException: I covered that in my other answer. ;) This one contains a disclaimer to the same effect, based upon the question title.

Comment: @NullUserException thanks for understanding! =) Will mark this as answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 2):

There's been a lot of discussion about your syntax, but I think I can fill in the blanks well enough to understand what you're asking. You want to know whether JavaScript is executed sequentially; specifically, if a function call will pause execution of the calling function until the called function terminates.

### General case

For the general case, the answer is yes. Here's some example code to illustrate this:

```
var count = 0;
var result = "";

function a() {
    result += "first part of A. \n";    
    b();    
    result += "last part of A. ";
}

function b() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        count++;
    }
    result += "even after " + count + " cycles, A waits for B. \n";
}

a();
console.log(result);
```

Runnable version on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorgan123/574Rh/

Try it out. You'll see that the result is:

```
first part of A. 
even after 100000 cycles, A waits for B. 
last part of A.
```

### Exceptions to the rule

There are exceptions to this, and they're very important. When you set an interval or timeout, the program starts a timer and plans to run a function when the timer finishes. But it doesn't wait around for that to happen; once the timer has started, the rest of the program goes on with its other tasks:

```
//won't do what you want:
result += "first part of A ";  
setInterval(b, 1000);
result += "last part of A ";
```

In this case, when `a()` is finished running, `result` will be:

```
first part of A, last part of A
```

In fact, that's all you'll see, because `console.log(result)` will run before `b()` does.

Another important case where JS defers execution is in AJAX calls; this trips people up all the time. Here's an example of this mistake:

```
//also won't do what you want:
result += "first part of A ";
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    result += "now with AJAX! "; 
});
result += "last part of A ";
```

Again, result will be `first part of A, last part of A` when `console.log(result)` runs. The only way to guarantee your code runs *after* the AJAX call is by putting it in the callback:

```
var result = "";

function a() {
    result += "first part of A ";
    $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
        result += "now with AJAX! "; 
        result += "last part of A ";
        console.log(result);
    });
}

a();
```

### `alert()` and `confirm()`

One final note: Interestingly, the functions `alert()` and `confirm()` **do**, in fact, interrupt control flow. If your code looks like this:

```
result += "first part of A, ";  
result += confirm("what is your choice?"); //let's assume you click 'OK' here
result += ", last part of A";
```

...the result will be `first part of A, true, last part of A` no matter how long you wait to click OK. `confirm` and `alert` are the only cases (correct me if I'm wrong) where JavaScript will pause execution while it waits for some outside source.

Comment: Javascript _never_ runs asynchronously. However, using timeouts you can _defer_ the execution of certain blocks of code. They execute later, but still synchronously. That said, it's worth noting that the ECMAScript standard doesn't make any mandates in this regard either way.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel - You're right, of course. I shouldn't have used synchronous/ansynchronous, I was just looking for a word to describe what I meant. I'll edit.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, assuming you want to call `doStuffA()`...

```
    function doStuffA() {
     // DO SOME THINGS

     doStuffB();

     // DO SOME MORE THINGS
    }
    function doStuffB() {
    // DO B THINGS
    }
```

The above will result in

```
1. DO SOME THINGS
2. DO B THINGS
3. DO SOME MORE THINGS
```

If you want the asynchronous approach you would use `setTimeout()`. Here are some docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

i.e.

```
    function doStuffA() {
     // DO SOME THINGS

       setTimeout(doStuffB,1);

     // DO SOME MORE THINGS
    }
    function doStuffB() {
    // DO B THINGS
    }
```

Comment: @NullUserException - Another assume probably from the responder to the OP.

Comment: `setTimeout` decouples calls from the current flow, but it does not make them asynchronous in such a fashion. They are simply injected into a subsequent event handling "tick".

Comment: Yes people an assumption was made based on the context of the question. You will notice several other people made the same assumption. Most of your answers are simply pointing out the OPs lack of presentation. How about you try to help instead?

Comment: @Malk: "Helping" comes in many forms. Training someone to be precise is far more useful in the long run than anything else we could do here.